# remote delete a message through ajax in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am developing an application which can able to create and update messages through ajax calls.Now I am trying to delete a message and update through ajax but i was failed.

here is my my code

**_message.html.erb**

```
<p><%=message.body%></p>
<p><%=link_to "delete", message_path(message.id), method: :delete,:remote=> true, :class=>"delete-msg" %> </p>
```

id of above division is `#messages`

**messages_controller**

```
def destroy
    @message = current_user.messages.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @message.destroy
    @messages = current_user.messages.all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to current_user}
    format.js
    end
end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#messages").load("<%= j render @messages%>");
```

The messages can be deleted but the division is not updating,pls help me...thanks in advance...

Comment: Try: $("#messages").html("<%= j render @messages%>");

Comment: Can you try $("#messages").html("<%=j render @messages%>");

Comment: perfect...it worked for me...pls write as answer below...

Comment: @vjnan369 if you think that my answer is correct then please mark it as correct in my answer.

Comment: @dipakgupta I am unable to accept the answer...as...the question was posted earlier...it saying wait for 3 min to accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try with this:

```
$("#messages").html("<%= j render @messages%>");
```